# Do I need to check in vbproj file in TFS when I add a new image in the solution?

Tags: vb.net, tfs

I have added a new image in the web folder and my .vbproj file reflects that change as

Do I need to check in this .vbproj file as well in TFS to reflect this change or not required? Please advise as I am trying to know the process.

Answer (score -1):

The VBPROJ file contains a reference to, among other things, each item that belongs to the project. If you don't check in the project file after that change and then someone else syncs or you restore from your repo then you will get that image file in your project folder but it won't be part of the project, so you won't see it in the Solution Explorer (unless you click *Show All Files*) and it won't be included in the build process.